# Is the Steam version of Indigo Prophecy censored?

Tags: steam, indigo-prophecy

Indigo Prophecy is a game that has been sold in two versions:

- the original version, which was sold in Europe under the name "Fahrenheit", and contained a love scene which was censored in
- the US version that was released under the name "Indigo Prophecy".

I saw that the game was sold on Steam, but without any information about which version it is. I've sent an email to the steam helpdesk and they responded that they didn't know if it was censored or not.

Since the game is sold under the name "Indigo Prophecy" I guess it must be the censored US version, but can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread on gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/926558-indigo-prophecy/52770410) it's definitely the censored version.

Comment: Thanks! Well, too bad Steam doesn't sell the original version. I'll have to find it somewhere else, maybe I can find an used box somewhere. Strange that the guy at the Steam helpline didn't know which version they sell.

Comment: I played that not knowing it was censored... now I want the full version! /cc @Gimly

Answer (score 6):

As of 2015, Steam's catalogue includes [Fahrenheit: Indigo Prophecy **Remastered**](https://store.steampowered.com/app/312840/Fahrenheit_Indigo_Prophecy_Remastered/) (the only version available - it seems the original US version (app ID [9740](https://steamdb.info/app/9740/)) has been removed).

The remastered version offers the

> Uncut version of the game — Unlike the original North American
>   release, **Remastered contains all of the game's original scenes,
>   uncensored and uncut.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, As far as I know you can only buy the Director's Cut (AO Rating) At [Direct 2 Drive here](http://www.direct2drive.com/725/product/Buy-Fahrenheit:-Indigo-Prophecy-Directors-Cut-Download)